# Python Class on google colab

Tags: python, class, error-handling

**Why my code can only print until 3, then I get 0 after all?**

Can anyone help me with this question?

I don't know where is the Error.

Thank you!

Here are my code:

```
class Queue:
  def __init__ (self,size):
    self.__contents = [0] * 10
    self.__head = 0
    self.__count = -1
  
  def is_full(self):
    return self.__head > len(self.__contents)

  def is_empty(self):
    return self.__head == 0

  def add(self, x):
    if self.is_full():
      return
    else:
      self.__contents[self.__head] = x
      self.__head += 1
  
  def get(self):
    if self.is_empty():
      return
    else:
      self.__head -= 1
      self.__count += 1
      return self.__contents[self.__count]
```

Here are my result:

```
my_queue = Queue(5)
my_queue.add(4)
my_queue.add(10)
my_queue.add(3)
print(my_queue.get()) # should print 4 I get 4. Success!
print(my_queue.get()) # should print 10 I get 10. Success!
my_queue.add(7)
print(my_queue.get()) # should print 3 I get 3. Success!
my_queue.add(6)
my_queue.add(5)
my_queue.add(4)
my_queue.add(3)     # should print 7 but I get 0. Fail
print(my_queue.get()) # should print 6 but I get 0. Fail
print(my_queue.get()) # should print 5 but I get 0. Fail
print(my_queue.get()) # should print 4 but I get 0. Fail
print(my_queue.get()) # should print 3 but I get 0. Fail
```

Answer (score 1):

self.__head is the index of the newest element + 1 and you don't actually remove any element from the queue when calling the get method. There is no need to decrease self.__head inside the get method. Doing that next added element will replace the old ones. Remove "self.__head -= 1" and everything will work (as long as you won't add more than 10 elements to the queue).

However, array based queue is a bad idea. To implement a queue you should use something like linked lists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did work!

**May I ask what should I do if I want to add more than 10 elements to the queue?**
**Where in the code should I adjust?**
Thank you!

Comment: It is because len(self.__contents) equals 10 so you can make self.__contents bigger. In the __init__ you probably ment `self.__contents = [0] * size` instead of `self.__contents = [0] * 10`. This will make queue custom size however still it will be possible to add size number of elements in the entire queue life (you do not remove elements). I don't know any solution to this other than an append function (overkill and does not solve the memory issue). That is why I recommend to use a linked list.